# sql server management studio stopped working

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I have installed SQL Server Management studio 2012 in my system, but when i try to launch application it shows a message "SQL Server Management studio stopped working-windows will close the program and will try to find solution.please give me a solution.
 i have a doubt is it mandatory to have visual studio in my system for sql server to work??

Comment: What about just reinstalling of management studio? And no, it is not mandatory to have VS installed in order for SSMS to work.

Comment: also check eventvwr logs

Comment: reinstalling din't work @AndyKorneyev